# IGNORE: I just renamed the title to try something out

Tags: c

I'm trying to assign a number in an array one by one. If the pointer is pointing at the first element of the array, then it means that the array empty and it will be assigned with a number. But for some reason, it doesn't seem to move the pointer to the next element. How can I fix this?

```
unsigned char number= '1';
unsigned char array[8];
int count = 0;
unsigned char *ptr;



int main(){
    while(count < 5){
        reserve();
        count ++;
        ptr++; //move to next element
    }
}

void reserve(void){
    if(ptr = array){          //if pointer is at the first element of the
        *ptr = number;         //array then it means it's empty
    }
    else{                    //not empty array
        *ptr = number;
    }  
}
```

Comment: You need to CALL the method `toarray`: `print( count_matrix.toarray() )` currently you are only printing the methods `__repr__(self)` which tells you about the class/method and whats in cv:  *4 stored elements in sparse Row Format*.

Comment: Sparse whatever means: you have an array of 1million times 1million values of which most are 0/None - so you do not store 1000000*1000000 items ( 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,.......,1,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, ....), instead you store (row,colum):value  for the 100 or so values that are NOT 0/None: hence _sparse_ - which is more efficient in terms of space and access.

Comment: [wikipedia sparse matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix)

Comment: This function returned a `sparse.matrix`, that's defined in the `scipy.sparse` module.  `toarray()` is a method that converts it to a conventional `numpy` array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [1]: from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
   ...: 
   ...: text  = ["London Paris London", "Paris Paris London"]
   ...: cv = CountVectorizer()
   ...: count_matrix = cv.fit_transform(text)
   ...:
```

The result is a matrix defined in the `scipy.sparse` module.  It can be displayed in various ways:

```
In [2]: count_matrix
Out[2]: 
<2x2 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 4 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [3]: print(count_matrix)
  (0, 0)    2
  (0, 1)    1
  (1, 0)    1
  (1, 1)    2
In [4]: count_matrix.toarray()
Out[4]: 
array([[2, 1],
       [1, 2]])
In [5]: count_matrix.A   # shorthand for toarray()
Out[5]: 
array([[2, 1],
       [1, 2]])
```

In this case the matrix isn't 'sparse', that is all values are non-zero.  But in general this type of matrix used when many of the values are zero.  Usually we define such a matrix with

```
from scipy import sparse
M = sparse.csr_matrix(...)   # see docs
```

`sklearn` can use sparse matrix inputs in some of its functions, and in this case creates one.  See the `CountVectorizer` docs for more details.